# how to compare two columns in two different data frames and count the occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following two data frames:

```
dic_1 = {'intA': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'D', 4: 'A', 5: 'F', 6: 'C', 7: 'H', 8: 'D', 9: 'X', 10: 'A', 11: 'C', 12: 'X'}, 'intB': {0: 'FG', 1: 'GH', 2: 'SD', 3: 'KJ', 4: 'FG', 5: 'WE', 6: 'NB', 7: 'GH', 8: 'AA', 9: 'ZX', 10: 'QQ', 11: 'OI', 12: 'XX'}}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dic_1)
df_1


   intA intB
0   A   FG
1   B   GH
2   A   SD
3   D   KJ
4   A   FG
5   F   WE
6   C   NB
7   H   GH
8   D   AA
9   X   ZX
10  A   QQ
11  C   OI
12  X   XX

dic_2 = {'ref': {0: 'AA',
  1: 'GH',
  2: 'CD',
  3: 'FG',
  4: 'XX',
  5: 'TY',
  6: 'ZX',
  7: 'SD',
  8: 'KJ',
  9: 'IU'}}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dic_2)
df_2
    ref
0   AA
1   GH
2   CD
3   FG
4   XX
5   TY
6   ZX
7   SD
8   KJ
9   IU
```

What I want is a resulting data frame that looks like this:

```
  symbol    count
0   A   3
1   B   1
2   D   2
3   F   0
4   C   0
5   H   1
6   X   2
```

Logic: For each item in 'intA' column in df_1, if its corresponding item in 'intB' column in df_1 exists in 'ref' column in df_2, increase the count by one.
For example, there are four occurrences of 'A' in 'intA' but only three of its corresponding items in 'intB' column exists in 'ref' in df_2, so the count is 3.

Comment: you can also try for loop for both the column to compare .
may be it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filter in `df_1`, then count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with add missing values by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), last convert `Series` to 2 columns `Dataframe`:

```
df = (df_1.loc[df_1['intB'].isin(df_2['ref']), 'intA']
          .value_counts()
          .reindex(df_1['intA'].unique(), fill_value=0)
          .rename_axis('symbol')
          .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
  symbol  count
0      A      3
1      B      1
2      D      2
3      F      0
4      C      0
5      H      1
6      X      2
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a boolean mask with `isin` to test whether the elements in `intB` column matches with any element from the `ref` column, then `sum` the `True` values in this mask per unique value in `intA`

```
df_1.set_index('intA')['intB'].isin(df_2['ref'])\
    .sum(level=0).rename_axis('symbol').reset_index(name='count')
```

---

```
  symbol  count
0      A      3
1      B      1
2      D      2
3      F      0
4      C      0
5      H      1
6      X      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option via `groupby`:

```
result = df_1.assign(count=df_1.intB.isin(df_2.ref)).groupby(
    'intA', sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'count': sum})
```

OUTPUT:

```
  intA  count
0    A      3
1    B      1
2    D      2
3    F      0
4    C      0
5    H      1
6    X      2
```